# A java workflow engine that I can integrate with a desktop swing application

Tags: java, workflow

I have developed a java swing desktop application that many of my clients are using. They have requested me to develop a 'workflow' wrapper around the tasks that they perform on the swing app.

Are there any open source workflow engines that support the below features for a desktop app?

1. Workflows should be created by my clients. They can add 2 kinds of steps. One is a manual step where the user has to track the step to completion. Meaning manually mark it complete. The other is a system step, where the app has the capacity to track a particular step when its done. If its done it will automatically mark it as complete. 
   I can code in the GUI. I need APIs of the workflow engine to call into create a new workflow.
2. The user can add/edit new steps to an existing workflow. In this case all existing workflow instances of the edited workflow should be migrated onto the new workflow template.
3. Once a user logs in all existing tasks on his queue should be displayed. Hence i need an API to call into to provide this for the user.

The above satisfies most of the requirements. If there are any more I think I should be able to handle it. I looked at this webpage:

http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

It describes a whole lot of workflow engines, but I am not able to find something that I can integrate onto a desktop app.

Some technical details of the app:

1. Developed on swing.
2. Uses a mysql database.
3. Also has a shared network folder that multiple users share
    (So any file based workflow engines are okay too, as long as multiple users can startup a workflow engine on each of their systems).

Comment: [programmer.stackexchange.com](http://programmer.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Take a look at [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/).